# SharePoint 2010 content type doesn't display in SharePoint 2013

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, external-contenttype

I have created External content type using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff464321(v=office.14).aspx) link. It is created successfully, but the issue I am facing is the created content type are not visible for external list creation. But my external content type is visible in BDC service as well in designer.

This is SharePoint 2010 code to create external content type and my environment is SharePoint 2013. Is that an issue? How can I make sure my content type are visible for external list?

As I have to pass my data source, I can't use SharePoint 2013 BDC model. And as I have to create them programmatically, I can't use  SharePoint Designer either. Can any one suggest any other solution for this issue?

Comment: For SharePoint related questions, please use the SharePoint stack exchange site (SharePoint.StackExchange.com)